# Interpolate irregularly sampled data to a regular grid

Tags: coordinates, netcdf, xarray

I'm using .nc files with spatially referenced timeseries data in xarray, i.e. inherently 3-dimensional data (lat, lon, time). My issue is, that the dataset's coordinates `lat` and `lon` are merged to a `site_id`, therefore my xarray has the coordinates `site_id` and `time`, and `lat` and `lon` coordinates are stored as data variables:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 166560, site_id: 2751) 
Coordinates:
    time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 ... 2018-12-31T23:00:00
    site_id      (site_id) float64 20.0 21.0 22.0 ... 2.769e+03 2.77e+03
Data variables:
    data         (site_id, time) float64 0.5698 0.5349 0.4891 ... 0.5762 0.6608
    lat          (site_id) float64 36.77 37.21 38.52 38.96 ... 35.02 35.45 35.88
    lon          (site_id) float64 -9.008 -9.131 -9.512 ... 34.39 34.54 34.69
```

What I want to achieve is a restructured dataset, where `time`, `lat` and `lon` are set as coordinates, and the original index `site_id` is dropped:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 166560, lat: 2751, lon: 2751) 
Coordinates:
    time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 ... 2018-12-31T23:00:00
    lat           (lat) float64 36.77 37.21 38.52 38.96 ... 35.02 35.45 35.88
    lon           (lon) float64 -9.008 -9.131 -9.512 ... 34.39 34.54 34.69
Data variables:
    data         (time, lat, lon) float64 0.5698 0.5349 0.4891 ... 0.5762 0.6608
```

Following a comparable thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015638/xarray-reshape-data-split-dimension), I tried to specify `site_id` as MultiIndex and unstacking it with `ds.set_index(site_id=("lat","lon")).unstack("site_id")` which did not work due to a MemoryError:

`numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 9.17 TiB for an array with shape (166560, 2751, 2751) and data type float64`

Is there a way to solve this problem without having 10TB of RAM?

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to create that restructured dataset? Because it will be a huge file thats mostly empty.

Comment: Why do you think that the file will be mostly emtpy? I need to select the data by lat/lon [i.e. `ds.sel(lat=slice(..), lon=slice(..))`] and interpolate all timeseries within the set to match a predefined grid [i.e. `ds.data.interp_like(grid, method="nearest")`]. Once this is done, I can merge this dataset with other datasets also aligned to the grid.

Comment: For each time-slice: In your original dataset, you have 2751 data-points. In the transformed dataset, you have 2,751*2,751 = 7,568,001 data-points of which 7,565,250 points are empty or "missing data".

Comment: You are right, good point. As mentioned above, I would like to project the data to a defined grid, e.g. 0.25° resolution over some lat/lon range. For simple point data, I would just define the grid an make a spatial join in GIS. But I have no idea what to do with timeseries data. I was thinking of defining the grid as e.g. GeoTIFF and interpolating all timeseries data to the grid's centroids. To do this, I first wanted to replace the site_ids by the lat lon coordinates (as my grid is also expressed in lat/lon coordinates) and perform `ds.data.interp_like(grid, method="nearest")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import modules and create some test data:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Determine dimension sizes
nt = 20
nsite_id = 200

# Create dummy coordinates
times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2018-01-01", periods = nt)
site_ids = np.linspace(0, nsite_id-1, nsite_id)
data = np.random.rand(nsite_id, nt)
lats = np.linspace(50, 60, nsite_id)
lons = np.linspace(20, 10, nsite_id)
np.random.shuffle(lats)
np.random.shuffle(lons)

# Create dummy dataset
ds = xr.Dataset({"data": (["site_id", "time"],data), "lat": (["site_id"], lats), "lon": (["site_id"], lons)}, coords = {"time": times, "site_id": site_ids})

print(ds)
```

Gives the following dataset.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (site_id: 200, time: 20)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 ... 2018-01-01
  * site_id  (site_id) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 ... 196.0 197.0 198.0 199.0
Data variables:
    data     (site_id, time) float64 0.04678 0.2404 0.6671 ... 0.00551 0.3914
    lat      (site_id) float64 59.95 52.36 54.27 50.1 ... 55.08 50.35 58.79
    lon      (site_id) float64 19.4 15.28 13.62 16.98 ... 19.5 14.82 18.89 11.31
```

Then for your first question, you can select data by lat/lon "slices" like this:

```
# Select data by lat/lon
ds_selected = ds.where((ds.lat > 51) &
                       (ds.lat < 59) &
                       (ds.lon > 11) &
                       (ds.lon < 19), drop = True)
```

Just to get an idea of what happens when you do the `.unstack` thing:

```
test = ds_selected.set_index(site_id=("lat", "lon")).unstack("site_id")
test["data"].isel(time=0).plot()
```

You can see that there is a lot of missing data:

[image: The data is sampled irregular and there are a lot of empty pixels.]

To interpolate our selected data onto a regular grid, we can use [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), vectorize it using `xr.apply_ufunc` and allow for dask chunks like this:

```
# Define function to interpolate sampled data to grid.
def interp_to_grid(u, xc, yc, new_lats, new_lons):
    new_points = np.stack(np.meshgrid(new_lats, new_lons), axis = 2).reshape((new_lats.size * new_lons.size, 2))
    z = griddata((xc, yc), u, (new_points[:,1], new_points[:,0]), method = 'nearest', fill_value = np.nan)
    out = z.reshape((new_lats.size, new_lons.size), order = "F")
    return out 

# Create chunks (you'd probably want to write `ds_selected` to disk 
# first using `.to_netcdf()` and then load it from there as a `dask.array`).
ds_selected = ds_selected.chunk({"site_id": -1, "time": 10})

values = ds_selected.data
lons = ds_selected.lon
lats = ds_selected.lat

# Create some dummy grid on which to interpolate.
_new_lats = np.linspace(ds_selected.lat.min(), ds_selected.lat.max(), 120)
_new_lons = np.linspace(ds_selected.lon.min(), ds_selected.lon.max(), 90)
new_lons = xr.DataArray(_new_lons, dims = "lon", coords = {"lon": _new_lons})
new_lats = xr.DataArray(_new_lats, dims = "lat", coords = {"lat": _new_lats})

# Vectorize the `interp_to_grid` function.
gridded_ds = xr.apply_ufunc(interp_to_grid,
                     values, lons, lats, new_lats, new_lons,
                     vectorize = True,
                     dask = "parallelized",
                     input_core_dims = [['site_id'],['site_id'],['site_id'],["lat"],["lon"]],
                     output_core_dims = [['lat', 'lon']],
                     )
```

Now we have the data interpolated on a grid. Lets make a plot.

```
# Create a plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
gridded_ds.isel(time=0).plot(ax = ax)
ax.scatter(lons, lats, c = values.isel(time=0), edgecolors="white")
```

[image: White circles show the sampled data, its seems to match nicely with the interpolated data.]

Comment: Thanks Bert! Works super smooth! I converted the `gridded_ds` from DataArray back to a dataset using `gridded_ds.to_dataset(name="data")`.

Comment: @Jonny32418 feel free to accept the answer and upvote ;)